# Honeywell pressure sensor TSCDANN150PGUCV amplifier circuit

Tags: arduino, amplifier, sensor, pressure

I have been trying to find amplifier circuits for this sensor. The [datasheet](https://www.verical.com/datasheet/honeywell-pressure-tscdann150pgucv-1798831.pdf) has one on page 29 (pic attached). However, as seen in the pic, the values for the resistors are not specified and we can't find them in the datasheet. Does anyone know what the values are? We've tried some resistor values but we don't get reasonable values when we test the sensor.

Any help, or link with an example project where this sensor is used, is appreciated. I haven't found anything from my google searches

[image: pic of the amplifier given in the datasheer]

Comment: If you need an Arduino compatible board you can get it from Analog Devices: https://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/user-guides/eval-adicup360/hardware/cn0216 or similar

Answer (score 1):

You can use values that you have available; try values between 20 and 100K.  If you have enough of them, R2's, R3's, and R4's can all have the same value.  Gain will be 1+[(2*R2)/R1].  The offset adjustment should be small if used only to take care of resistor tolerances but is necessary if the input can be both positive and negative, to provide a reference, because the output cannot go negative.  If you do use the offset, the R4 attached to the offset should have a slightly lower value.  This R4 added to the parallel combination of R5 and R6 should then be equal the other R4.